# highlighting table rows after removing table row

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to highlight all even rows in a table after deleting a row. The tr is removed but the re-highlighting does not work (I get two rows together that are highlighted). Here's my code;

```
$( "#tr_id" ).remove();

// re-highlight table rows 
$("#table_id" ).removeClass("highlight");
$("#table_id tbody tr:even" ).addClass("highlight");
```

However, if I add an alert or something to slow the execution between removing and highlighting it works.

```
$( "#tr_id" ).remove();

alert( 'slow execution' );

// re-highlight table rows 
$("#table_id" ).removeClass("highlight");
$("#table_id tbody tr:even" ).addClass("highlight");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your code exactly like that? I think .remove() is supposed to work in serial, so a callback wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jasie you're right. Sorry this was me being stupid. 
The code works as it is written above, but in my actual code I had the remove() in ajax.success function and my re-highlight code below it. I moved my re-highlight code into the success function and of course it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think using JQuery's [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function is ideal for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not supporting IE < 9 and CSS3 is an option, you could use the [`nth-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) pseudo-class and avoid the issue altogether:

`#table_id tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: yellow; }`

Removing `tr`s doesn't effect the application of the pseudo class: http://jsfiddle.net/axWYj/